# Load DLL create Instance and Unload

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I have a Application which copies a DLL (UserControlLibrary) to its own Debug/Release folder and loads it using this Code:

```
AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "DLLs (*.dll)|*.dll";
if (dialog.ShowDialog().Value)
{
    string newLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + dialog.SafeFileName;
    File.Copy(dialog.FileName, newLocation, true);
    Assembly assembly = appDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(newLocation));
    UserControl userControl = (UserControl) assembly.CreateInstance("WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1");
}
```

I now add that UserControl to a Grid using:

```
grid.Children.Add(userControl);
```

Works fine. Now I try to unload the DLL using:

```
AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
grid.Children.Clear();
```

If I now try to load the DLL (because it changed meanwhile) again using the above code I get an error telling me the file is in use (File.Copy).

I've read a lot of things and my guess is that I'm not allowed to use the UserControl like I did (because that loads into the Main AppDomain). How do I have to change the Code to make it work?

I've also read a lot of things about using MarshalByRefObject but unfortunately I was unable to implement it in this project. A example or modification of the code above would be nice.

**EDIT:**

From the comments I've read so far (especially from svick) it looks like I have to use "AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap" instead of "AppDomain.Load".
I've seen that approach already while searching for a solution earlier but as svick mentioned that doesn't work because a UserControl can't inherit from MarshalByRefObject.

Does anyone know another way?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". We use tags for that on [SO].

Comment: Your types are probably crossing domain boundaries, hence they will be stuck in the 'main' running appdomain. Use the `MarhshalByRefObject` suggestion along with common interfaces for remotable objects. It's hard, but once you get it, you will understand :)  BTW it is a good exercise in learning remoting.

Comment: UserControl can't inherit from MarhshalByRefObject... ?

Answer (score 2):

Read [the documentation for `AppDomain.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58.aspx). It specifically says that this method loads the assembly *both* into the assembly you are calling the method on and into the current assembly. So, even when you unload the app domain, the assembly still stays loaded in the current assembly.

I'm not sure there is a way around this as you can't make `UserControl` inherit from `MarhshalByRefObject`.

Comment: Yup. I had the same problem using AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap as well.

Comment: So there is no way to use AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap  for WPF UserControls to load assemblies into the different AppDomain?

Comment: @Peretz As far as I know, yeah, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you call unload, the AppDomain is not immediately unloaded ([see MSDN for the full article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx)):

> **When a thread calls Unload, the target domain is marked for unloading.**
>   The dedicated thread attempts to unload the domain, and all threads in
>   the domain are aborted. If a thread does not abort, for example
>   because it is executing unmanaged code, or because it is executing a
>   finally block, then after a period of time a
>   CannotUnloadAppDomainException is thrown...

Comment: Interesting how to handle an actual unload of AppDomain

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this quote from the MSDN article for [AppDomain.Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx) could explain things:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0 there is a thread dedicated to unloading application domains. This improves reliability, especially when the .NET Framework is hosted. When a thread calls Unload, the target domain is marked for unloading. The dedicated thread attempts to unload the domain, and all threads in the domain are aborted. If a thread does not abort, for example because it is executing unmanaged code, or because it is executing a finally block, then after a period of time a CannotUnloadAppDomainException is thrown in the thread that originally called Unload. If the thread that could not be aborted eventually ends, the target domain is not unloaded. Thus, in the .NET Framework version 2.0 domain is not guaranteed to unload, because it might not be possible to terminate executing threads.

Maybe there are some rogue threads that are keeping the app domain alive and therefore also keeping your file locked.

As a workaround, you could copy the DLLs to random file names instead.

Comment: So you would say there is nothing wrong with my usage of the usercontrols instance? Its not being loaded into the main AppDomain?
P.S.: I'm currently using the workaround you mentioned.

Comment: It's hard to know; do your controls do anything tricky like thread spawning?

Comment: No. They are completely on their own and don't communicate with each other (yet).